# There is always a error when i'm going to run a android app

Tags: android-studio, openglrenderer

when i am going to run a android app,there is always a text which is " E/OpenGLRenderer: construct program from binary, position:0, texCoord-1" in my logcat

[image]

Comment: you can update error code here  instead visiting a link and update what have you tried etc .